# Anlysing variables that have been measured at macro and micro level

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing

I have a dataset with the following variables:

Resources (Likert 1-5) (IV),
Training (Likert 1-5) (IV),
Pay (Likert 1-5) (IV),
.
.
.
.
, Business unit level performance (e.g. Near misses) (DV)

‘Business unit level performance’ have been measured at business unit level (e.g. near misses in that business unit during February) and the rest of the variables have been measured at individual (employee) level.

There are 30 business units in the organisation and each business unit has 10-15 employees. Some business units hit the target every month and some of them don’t (Let’s say they all produce the same product). The question that I need to answer is that: whether any of the IVs impact the DV. In other words if any of the IVs are the reason for variation in the business unit performance. I was wondering if someone here could suggest a technique to answer this question.

Thank you.